# How to copy a line from a table to the same table and re-using the new line RecordID

Tags: sql-server

I have table with a RecordID that is the PK, I'd like to copy one line, to a new line in the same table, but I'd like to use the number of this new line to create a key code I have in table.

I'm using

```
INSERT INTO mytable ([field 1], [field 2], [field 3], [field 4])
SELECT 'New Data for Field 1', [field 2]+[field 3] + [NewRecordID]
FROM mytable
```

I tried to use the Row_number function, but it always generate a 1 every time I run the query.

Any ideas of I could do to use the new auto-generated number in my query while I copy the data?

Edit:
You'll find on the attached file, my table design, and some data.

The idea is to take the (Program Default) country, to copy it with to a new country.
I would like to create, while copying existing data for a new country, take the new RecordID that'll be created when line will created and generate a KeyCovCountry including this new generated number.

[image]

Comment: can you explain with some sample data and expected result

Comment: use an identity column would be one way (and don't forget a where clause).

Comment: Your code attempt doesn't make much sense.  You're trying to insert two columns into four?

Comment: @Tab Alleman, it was just for the exemple, consider that my query has the same number of columns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is by making `KeyCovCountry` a Computed Column.

Comment: This could be a good idea, but when I try to create my formula, I have error message because of the data type. I'm trying to concatenate the RecordID with a part of my KeyFNCode. The message is: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1FN12345620170206' to data type int."

Comment: In your formula, you need to `CAST` the RecordID as a `varchar(31)`